# Accessing Google Maps URL outside the Javascript API

Tags: google-maps, google-api-javascript-client

I have a web app and have successfully configured it to access google maps from this URL outside the JavaScript API using this URL:

http://mt0.google.com/vt/lyrs=y&hl=en&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}&s=Ga

The app uses the imagery as background in a PDF report that members of the public can download - this is going to be a free service.

I contacted Google Maps support to ask them if this was allowed under their Terms of Services Agreement but they have referred me to here.

Could I please get an answer as to whether this is allowed or whether I need to enter into a licensing agreement or subscription - and if so what kind?  Or alternatively refer me to where I am best to direct this inquiry.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about terms of use (legal issues), not coding.

Comment: Really weird that Google Maps Platform support redirect you to StackOverflow. To my knowledge the direct access to tile imagery is not allowed by ToS, but Google agents should know this better than SO community.

Comment: I thought it was really weird too - its proving really hard to get an answer to something I thought was a simple question.  Here is the direct quote from the google support person's email when I asked the same question posted earlier:

"For more information, you may submit your inquiries on Google Maps Stackoverflow, as one of our developer will get back to you if you are allowed to access URL outside of the Javascript API according to the terms and conditions. "

Comment: I agree @xomena. Cate, would you be able to provide us the case number so we can check?

Answer (score 0):

There must be a miscommunication with regards to your concern when you reached out to the support team of the Google Maps Platform API, I would highly recommend that you file another support case via https://console.cloud.google.com/google/maps-apis/support as only the support team of the Google Maps Platform can share more knowledge about your concern as this will require internal investigation as well.

Comment: To further help you, can you also share the case number that you filed wherein the support agent redirect you in SO?

Comment: Hi Shawn, I don't have a case number because all I did was make an inquiry to Google Cloud. I tried this link you provided above but seems I need to already have a subscription in order to place a support request.  I'm just looking for advice on whether I need to subscribe at all at this stage - just trying to do the right thing and make sure I'm not breaching anything by accessing the service, Cate